# Viterbi algorithm for object tracking

Tags: algorithms, hidden-markov-models

I want to solve a problem of object tracking along time. The problem is - I have a sequence of images, and I need to find and track the creation of the objects, than their movement, and than their disappearance. There can be up to 3 objects overall, and sometimes there are less, or none. Another limitation is that for consecutive images there is a maximum distance that an object can move.

The practice I use is - estimating the locations for the objects in each image separately (using a neural network), up to 3 locations per image, and than filtering out clear mistakes (random locations with no continuation along time).

After a little research, I found that with some effort I can translate this problem into a hidden Markov model, and this one can be solved with Viterbi algorithm. The problem is that for each image there are more than 100 possible object locations, and with 3 objects we get >= 100000 different states.

My question is whether there exists a designated algorithm for this case of object tracking along time? Or otherwise, if there's a good and efficient way I can fit Viterbi algorithm for this problem?

Thank for any help!

Comment: This sounds more like what Kalman filtering is for... which is close to you HMM idea, as both are used for state space models.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I checked how Kalman filter works and I don't understand 2 things about using it in my case - 1. is that I don't have an input control, I just get the net's predictions, and 2. I don't assume a gaussian noise. There is just a certain probability that the net misses the object/s, or create false detections. 
Is it still possible to use Kalman filter for this case? If so, I would be happy to understand how. Thanks a lot!